# Will bottling by pouring negatively impact the flavor of my beer?

Tags: bottling

This is my second homebrew.  I used a friend's siphoning equipment and bottle filler for my first batch, then got my own.

This second batch is a pumpkin spice porter.  It fermented for a week, and I racked to a carboy second vessel for a week.  When I was ready to bottle, I racked it to a bottling bucket with priming sugar, and then found out that the siphon hose did not fit my bottle filler.

So, I slowly used a sanitized, glass measuring cup, and would slowly put it into the beer in the bottling bucket, lift, and slowly pour beer into each bottle.  I tried to keep down oxygenation.

Has anyone else ever bottled this way?  If I drink soon, and not months from now, will I be ok?  How soon after bottling does oxygenation appear as a flaw in the beer?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about it.

The yeast will "wake up" with the sugar you added in the bottling bucket, and they will consume the vast majority of the oxygen that's been added to your bottles from agitation.   Drink as you would normally.   If you start getting hints of sherry or cardboard flavors, then maybe try and finish the beer soon after that.

The live yeast are your friends in this situation, though, and they are one of the easiest methods of keeping a beer stable.

Comment: I don't think there's enough fermentation going on in the bottle to consume much oxygen, at least according to info I've come across in the past.  Bt of the beer is consumed in the next month or so, I doubt there will be a problem.

Comment: thanks.  i'll be trying a first bottle today and will report back.  i appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure the spigot is sanitized you can place the bottle under the spigot and fill the bottle to approximately the same space at the top that the bottling cane leaves.  If you overfill you will most likely paint the walls with beer when a bottle explodes... But this is a completely acceptable way to bottle (just a little less accurate).